# How to do background jobs in an ASP.NET MVC 3 site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently working on an e-commerce site and there's one feature that i'm not very sure how to implement. Most of the time you just add product(s) to your cart and buy them, that's probably the simplest workflow. What i'm asking is a little different, what if there's a time limit for a product to buy ? I mean some sites give you an exact time limit to buy a product (like Soccer Manager), in those sites you can't hold a product forever, there's a 15 minutes limit for it and if you dont buy in that period, item will be released from your cart. (and most probably someone else will jump on it)

Now, as an ASP.NET MVC programmer i'd love to implement this feature but as i said, i'm not sure how to do it. I think when i add item to cart i need to hold the time (something like ItemAddedAt) and i need to release that item in x minutes so something needs to run x minutes later to release that product. Globally thinking, i think i need a service, when i add an item, i also need to subscribe it to this service and service runs a timer/job in the background. What i dont know/have no experience is this part, how to do that in an ASP.NET MVC project, is there a sample project, article, library or something like that ?

Of course i dont know if my logic is right for this problem, i need some guidance, if possible some source code to work on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there are no standard way to declare/program tasks within an MVC project. The recommended way to accomplish what you want would be to create a new Console Application project within your solution, and use the Windows Task Scheduler to execute every X minutes, releasing any products that have been more than X minutes in any cart.

For this to work, you will need to reference your MVC project from the new one (to get access to all the models) or, even better, create a Class Library project, move your Model/database classes there, and reference it from the MVC and Console projects.

---

All that being said, there is actually a small "hack" that can be used to get programmed tasks in an MVC project. You can use the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("Task", "1", null, 
            DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), 
            CacheItemPriority.Normal, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CheckCarts));
```

That line, that could be called, for example, from the Global.asax, would add a "Task" entry to the cache. The value stored ("1") is not important, the important thing is that the cache entry expires in five minutes and, when expired, calls the "CheckCarts" method (defined in the Global.asax, or in the class were you execute this code).

```
public void CheckCarts(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason) {
     // Insert your code here to check for expired carts
     (...)

     // We add the entry again to the cache, so that this method will be called again in 5 minutes.
     HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("Task", "1", null, 
            DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), 
            CacheItemPriority.Normal, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CheckCarts));
}
```

When the cache expires, the CheckCarts method is called, your code does whatever it has to do, and in the end adds itself to the Cache again, to be called in another 5 minutes.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the detailed explanation ^^

I think i won't prefer Windows Task Scheduler because from what i understand, if i use Scheduler that way then i need to run that service with very short periods or there'll be big time gaps between expiration time and next scheduled run time.

IMHO your second solution is more exciting because it gives you an exact trigger and it looks like it can be easily implemented but there's one question in my mind, is CacheItemRemovedCallback reliable enough to use in these kind of solutions ?

Comment: that kind of recursive implementation might as well work, but I immediately began to worry about call stack size in this case

Comment: @ArtemNikolov We actually used that code for the exactly the same reason (it is currently working in an e-commerce, for freeing stock), and it's been running for about 4 years, so I would guess so :)

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer Would there be recursion in this case? (I'm seriously asking) Whatever class/thread controls the HttpCache is getting a reference to the function that it has to call when the item expires, and it's that thread that is calling the CheckCarts method. The original thread that assigned the value (and the method reference), should be finished by then.

Comment: @salgiza good point... I think you're correct!  Kudos for a clever solution.  In any case, I still feel like this is a hack.  We've had situations at work that required tasks to execute at regularly timed intervals, and went with Quartz.net.  It was a great decision, as tasks can be created with minimal overhead and connection code.  If you find yourself doing this sort of thing more than once, I would recommend something like Quartz.net

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer I actually agree with you. We implemented the hack in one of our first projects (we needed a solution quickly, and most of the project had been already developed), but since then we always go with the first option I mentioned (we create two projects: models & web) and then add new projects (tasks, other apps that use the same models) to the solution. Anyway: as it works, it's fast to implement, and was used exactly for the the same reason, I would have felt guilty if I hadn't mentioned the HttpCache trick! :)

Answer (score 3):

This scenario just screams signalR.
It would allow you to do what you're asking in a simple way.

If the items in your cart have an expiry date you could have your view poll if any items have expired. If they have you could run the removal code for that item and update your ui.

Comment: I agree.  The removal doesn't matter until you try to view your cart.  So why run this background process at all?  Just check the cart for expiry before displaying it.  This will also save you the work of expiring abandoned carts.  And will save you having to monitor a set of batch jobs to make sure they're running.

Comment: @spaceman: I'll be sure to research about SignalR, a real-time library like that might do good here and you can do some nice UX tricks.

Comment: @Brian: I think there's a slight misunderstanding about this removal, this's not about buyer's cart, this's about that product's stock. After expiration you need to release that product so that some other person can buy it, until that time you need to show them a disabled buy button because item is still reserved. Of course for every request you need to check your stock anyway but now your inventory manager service'll need to check that reserved item's expiration as well. Instead of that i want that product signals that expiration so i can decrease internal messaging between components.

Comment: if i add an item to my basket, then that items stock count should decrease by the amount of items added to my cart. This is pretty simple.

during this time if anyone else checks the items availability, stock levels have been set (with disabled buttons as needed)

15 minutes later, if i haven't checked out, you tell the user "times up, sux2beu" and then move all the items out of the cart and back into general stock, increasing the available count of each item by the amount of items in the basket.

either way, its the client driving the server.